# Result set retrieved with some dbms of postgresql database does not match with php or python result set

Tags: php, postgresql, match, resultset, fetchall

**I have a strange problem**

I'm using a postgresql database, so  i've created a function with that return a query with the following data.

[Resultset of DBMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9kna.png)

When i want retrieve the data from a programing language how php or python, some rows and cells were altered.

The following picture is a 'var_dump' statement writed in php, and you can see that the first data is not equals with the result of the dbms

['var_dump' statement in php of the result set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbeUW.png)

Now the following picture is a 'print' statement written in python, i've calling the same function with the same parameters and occurs the same

['print' statement in python of the result set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVDU1.png)

For example, i have a row with the follow data
This is an example of data retrieved by the dbms DBeaver 7.3.3 and AquaDataStudio 18.0.18.
Check the values wrapped with *

```
Ac Diseño Y Maquinados S.A. De C.V. ADM120725CE8    **20105.00**    **170684.94**
```

Now when I obtain the values from some programming language, the result is the following

```
Ac Diseño Y Maquinados S.A. De C.V. ADM120725CE8    **297488.33** **171968.47**
```

---

**Here is the code**

**Code of the function that return the result set**

Returns this [Resultset of DBMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9kna.png)

```sql
create or replace function fn_reporte_cfdis(p_fecha_desde varchar,p_fecha_hasta varchar)
    returns table (
              razon_social varchar(254)
            , rfc varchar(254)
            , suma_emitidos NUMERIC
            , suma_recibidos NUMERIC
            , utilidad_fiscal NUMERIC
            , isr NUMERIC
            , ptu NUMERIC
            , dividendos NUMERIC
        ) language plpgsql
    as $$
        begin
            return query 
                SELECT 
                    CI.SNOMBRE RAZON_SOCIAL,
                    CI.SRFC RFC,
                    coalesce(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(EMITIDOS.TOTAL,'99G999G999D99'),'99G999G999D99'),0) SUMA_EMITIDOS,
                    coalesce(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(RECIBIDOS.TOTAL,'99G999G999D99'),'99G999G999D99'),0)SUMA_RECIBIDOS,
                    coalesce(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR((EMITIDOS.TOTAL - RECIBIDOS.TOTAL),'99G999G999D99'),'99G999G999D99'),0) UTILIDAD_FISCAL,
                    coalesce(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(((EMITIDOS.TOTAL - RECIBIDOS.TOTAL)*0.30),'99G999G999D99'),'99G999G999D99'),0) ISR,
                    coalesce(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(((EMITIDOS.TOTAL - RECIBIDOS.TOTAL)*0.10),'99G999G999D99'),'99G999G999D99'),0) PTU,
                    coalesce(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(((EMITIDOS.TOTAL - RECIBIDOS.TOTAL)*0.10),'99G999G999D99'),'99G999G999D99'),0) DIVIDENDOS
                FROM 
                    CLIENTES_IR CI
                LEFT JOIN 
                    (SELECT
                        CI.SRFC,
                        SUM(COALESCE(CS.SUBTOTAL,0)) AS TOTAL
                    FROM 
                        CLIENTES_IR CI 
                    LEFT JOIN 
                        CFDIS_SAT CS 
                    ON 
                        CS.RFCEMISOR = CI.SRFC
                    WHERE 
                        CS.TIPO = 'I' AND 
                        CS.RFCEMISOR = CI.SRFC AND
                        CS.FHEMISION BETWEEN to_date(p_fecha_desde,'DD-MM-YYYY') AND to_date(p_fecha_hasta,'DD-MM-YYYY')
                    GROUP BY CI.SRFC ) EMITIDOS ON CI.SRFC = EMITIDOS.SRFC
                LEFT JOIN
                    (SELECT
                        CI.SRFC,
                        SUM(COALESCE(CS.SUBTOTAL,0)) + COALESCE(EMITIDOS_NOMINA.SUBTOTAL,0) AS TOTAL
                    FROM 
                        CFDIS_SAT CS 
                    INNER JOIN 
                        CLIENTES_IR CI ON CS.RFCRECEPTOR = CI.SRFC
                    LEFT JOIN 
                        (SELECT
                            CI.SRFC,
                            SUM(COALESCE(CS.SUBTOTAL,0)) AS SUBTOTAL
                        FROM 
                             CFDIS_SAT CS
                        INNER JOIN CLIENTES_IR CI ON CS.RFCEMISOR = CI.SRFC
                        WHERE 
                            CS.TIPO = 'N' AND 
                            CS.FHEMISION BETWEEN to_date(p_fecha_desde,'DD-MM-YYYY') AND to_date(p_fecha_hasta,'DD-MM-YYYY')
                    GROUP BY CI.SRFC ) EMITIDOS_NOMINA ON CI.SRFC = EMITIDOS_NOMINA.SRFC
                WHERE 
                    CS.TIPO ='I' AND 
                    (CS.USOCFDI = 'G01' OR CS.USOCFDI = 'G03') AND
                    CS.FHEMISION BETWEEN to_date(p_fecha_desde,'DD-MM-YYYY') AND to_date(p_fecha_hasta,'DD-MM-YYYY')
                    GROUP BY CI.SRFC , EMITIDOS_NOMINA.SUBTOTAL) RECIBIDOS ON RECIBIDOS.SRFC    =   CI.SRFC;
        end;$$
```

**The code of the model class in php that connect to database and call the function**

```php
class ReporteCfdisModel
{
    private $connection;
    private $queryData;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->connection = Connection::get()->connection(); //Get the connection of a class, is a tipical connection with pg_connect()
        $this->queryData = IniUtils::getUtils("application", "QUERY"); // get data of .ini file (Not relevant for this case)
    }

    public function getAll()
    {
        try {

            $stmt = pg_prepare($this->connection, "get_all", "select * from fn_reporte_cfdis($1,$2)"); // Prepare the query
            $stmt = pg_execute($this->connection, "get_all", array("01-02-2021", "28-02-2021")); // execute the query and pass parameters
            
            var_dump(pg_fetch_all($stmt)); // The line that Shows in the second image.
            // return pg_fetch_all($stmt);
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            echo json_encode(new Response(500, $ex->getMessage(), ""), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        } finally {
            $stmt = null;
            $this->connection = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code of database connection

```php
class Connection
{
    private $configData;
    private $host;
    private $dbName;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $port;
    private static $instance = NULL;
    public $connectionData;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->configData = IniUtils::getUtils("application", "DB_PGSQL");

        if ($this->configData !== null || count($this->configData) > 0) {
            $this->host = $this->configData["db_host"];
            $this->dbName = $this->configData["db_name"];
            $this->user = $this->configData["db_user"];
            $this->password = $this->configData["db_password"];
            $this->port = $this->configData["db_port"];
        }
    }

    public static function get()
    {
        if (self::$instance === NULL) {
            self::$instance = new Connection();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function connection()
    {
        try {
            // $this->connectionData = new PDO('pgsql:host=' . $this->host . ';port=' . $this->port . ';dbname=' . $this->dbName, $this->user, $this->password);
            $strHost = 'host=' . $this->host . ' port=' . $this->port . ' dbname=' . $this->dbName . " user=" . $this->user . " password=" . $this->password;
            $this->connectionData = pg_connect($strHost);
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
        return $this->connectionData;
    }
}
```

It's all important code that make the logic.

---

***Whats Happened?***
I don't know what happens when I call the query or function with the dbms and why this data does not match the result set calling in some programming language.

Help me please!

Comment: You've posted a load of screenshots of the results, but no code. Something's wrong, but we have no way to know what. Post the code (not screenshots) into the question. While you're at it, post the relevant result data into the question instead of the screen shots. Please, make it easy for us!

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Thanks for the answer, im added the important code.